# Cake php multidimensional array

Tags: php, cakephp, multidimensional-array

I have an array which is coming from join query when i debug  found this output.
Here is my code in controller

```
$agetFeatureGigs = $this->Gigs->getFeatureGigs();
$this->set('agetFeatureGigs', $agetFeatureGigs);

$yourValue='7';
foreach($agetFeatureGigs as $key => $val) {
    $agetFeatureGigs[$key]['Gigs']['manual'] = $yourValue;
}
```

Output

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'usersjoin' => array(
            'action' => 'YES'
        ),
        'Gigs' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'username' => 'nmodi',
            'category' => 'Creativity  & Designing',
            'subcategory' => 'Logo Design',
            'picture' => 'Banner_logo1.jpg',
            'video' => '',
            'title' => 'I will design 2 AWESOME logo design in 48 hours',
            'delivery' => '24 Hrs',
            'workinghrs' => '3',
            'feature' => 'YES',
            'action' => 'YES',
            'del' => 'NO'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'usersjoin' => array(
            'action' => 'YES'
        ),
        'Gigs' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'username' => 'ptailor',
            'category' => 'Creativity  & Designing',
            'subcategory' => 'Logo Design',
            'picture' => '128.jpg',
            'video' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtCF5tyAr-o&feature=inp-gs-IOL-07-47',
            'title' => 'I will proofread and edit your document I will proofread and edit your document',
            'delivery' => '12 Hrs',
            'workinghrs' => '2',
            'feature' => 'YES',
            'action' => 'YES',
            'del' => 'NO'
        )
    )
)
```

but I need to add a field rating with manual values bellow del inside gigs array.
 Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to insert the same value into each `Gigs` array in your data you can use [CakePHP's Hash utility](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html#Cake%5CUtility%5CHash::insert) like this:-

```
Hash::($data, '{n}.Gigs.rating', $value);
```

Where `$data` is your array and `$value` is the value you want to insert with an associative key of `rating`.

`Hash` will work for both CakePHP 2 and 3. Just remember in Cake 3 you need to handle namespacing so the above can be done as:-

```
Cake\Utility\Hash::($data, '{n}.Gigs.rating', $value);
```

If you need to insert different values then you will need to loop over the array:-

```
foreach ($data as &$item) {
    $item['Gigs']['rating'] = $value;
}
```

Comment: to debug?  <?php debug($agetFeatureGigs);?>

Comment: @ggutigod in your question you are setting the View variable before altering the data. Is this correct? If you are trying to alter the value of `$agetFeatureGigs` in the view you need to use `$this->set()` after altering the data.

Comment: I meant which of the two methods for altering the array had you tried. The `Hash` method or the `foreach`.